# Server blocked on public Wifi

Tags: http, tcp, port

I have an application running on an AWS instance (computer A). I give input to this application and process output via Ajax from a webpage.

Everything works fine while I am on my company Wifi, however if I switch on a public Wifi, it appears that I am no more able to access this server from a Firefox webpage on computer B.

Port 3030 is opened on AWS (computer A). I imagined that the only requirements were port 3030 on AWS (computer A) and port 80 on the computer trying to access the application (computer B).

Where is my mistake ? Doesn’t the Ajax query go from 80 of machine B to 3030 of machine A for the query, and from 3030 of machine A to 80 of machine B for the answer ?

Comment: is the application being served over http on the standard port of 80? If so then the only requirement is port 80 being open on the Server (ComputerA?)  if it is being served over HTTP on port 3030, then that port would need to be open.  No ports needs to be open on computer B (client).  Client makes HTTP request to $port, gets data, Then Browser makes same requests to $port for the ajax calls.  Source ports from  Client will be random high ports (>1024 generally). I would verify that DNS / IP works outside of your corp network. could be firewall blocking at AWS?

Comment: also is this public wifi your company's public wifi? perhaps they are blocking outbound connections to non port 80 stuff?

Comment: The server serve over HTTP on port 3030. That port is already opened in AWS so I don't understand why it would be a firewall blocking at AWS ?
In addition, everything works when I am on my company Wifi or my phone's Wifi, the problem occurs when I am on a public Wifi. That's why I imagine that the problem is coming from the client. But if http requests and ajax calls from the client are made over the same $port, why would the ajax call never return a result ?

Comment: My company Wifi works without any problems (I can connect to everything), the public wifi that I have comes from somewhere else but I can't have any information or change anything on it.

Comment: so when on public wifi, you access the app on port 3030, it connects/loads but none of the ajax calls work? or can you not get to the app itself?

Comment: The only "connection" I have with this app is an ajax call.
My html page can be hosted on my computer, it doesn't change anything. So once my html page is loaded (from localhost or from anywhere else, it doesn't matter), this page try to load the data by connecting to the server port 3030. This is this connection that doesn't work on a public wifi. So I think that the connection/load you are talking about is referring to the unique action done with this server : the ajax call. I know it is a bit confusing, thanks for your patience and help !

Comment: ok so you are loading the page, and then it connects to the server on port 3030. How is that connection defined? by name? by ip address? when connected to public wifi, can  you telnet to port 3030 using the same information that is found in the config? IF you enable console / developer tools in browser do you see any logs/errors

Comment: Exactly. The connection is defined by IP address. When connected to company wifi, telnet works (it allows me to type something). When connected to public wifi, telnet doesn't work (throw me a fail when trying to connect). If I enable the firebug console, it shows "Aborted 9.93s" at the end of the GET line and there's also a "status text : timeout" in the object returned by the ajax call.

Comment: Have you tried with other public wifi providers? are there other ports that you can try to connect to on the AWS host (port 80 for example). Assuming that you are connecting to a public AWS instance (not one that you require VPN to), and on a public IP address. If you cannot connect to it via the public wifi, it would appear that wifi is blocking it somehow.  Could be waiting for you to complete captive portal? could be outbound connection acl that limits connections to 80/443/etc..  I've seen both.